# Strange behaviour with arrays in C

Tags: c, linux

sorry for my bad English. I'm new to Linux system programming and new to C programming as well. 
At the moment I'm trying to unlink files, to do this, I must store file path somewhere. I'm using 1024-element char array for each file. If I decrease the size of array, file descriptors become a mess. Sounds stupid, but it is. 
 Here's some code:

```
char path[1024], path2[1024];
const char *file_name = "myfile_1", *file_name2 = "myfile_2",*working_directory="/home/Alexander/lab01/";
strcpy(path, working_directory);
strcat(path, file_name);
strcpy(path2, working_directory);
strcat(path2, file_name);
```

then I open some files, read\write and so on. If path & path2 are 1024 bytes long, everything goes well..[image: all_ok]
but when I decrease path & path2 size to 512 or 256, some strange thing happens with memory and other file descriptors...
[image: all_crap]
I can't understand what's going on, please, help.
Code, where I read file:

```
fdesc_input = open("/dev/urandom",O_RDONLY);
if (fdesc_input < 0 ) {
    perror("Error opening /dev/urandom: ");
}
fdesc_output = open(path, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0777);
if (fdesc_output < 0 ) {
        perror("Error opening my file: ");
    }
buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(buffer_size); // make 1kb buffer

desired_filesize = 1024*10; // 10 kilobytes

int curr_size = 0;
while (curr_size < desired_filesize) {

           //AFTER NEXT LINE STRANGE HAPPENS
    ssize_t result = read(fdesc_input, &buffer, buffer_size);
    if (result < 0) {
        perror ("Error reading /dev/urandom: ");
        exit(1);
    }
    curr_size += result;
    write(fdesc_output, &buffer, buffer_size);
}
```

Comment: What you've shown looks OK; I suspect some of that "read/write and so on..." code (reads, in particular) may be involved. Can you show us the reads?

Comment: `read(fdesc_input, &buffer, buffer_size);` **is a bug**. You don't need the `&` here, likewise with the `write`. You may also optionally want to drop `malloc` and just use a fixed-size buffer, like `char buffer[buffer_size]` (make sure `buffer_size` is a compile-time constant).

Comment: Wow! That helped, thank you! Could you please post it as an answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `&buffer` to `read`, however, `buffer` itself is a pointer.  You pass the address of `buffer` which is a local variable. As a result, `read` reads data into the memory starting at this local variable and thus overwriting the other local variables.

Pass `buffer` instead of `&buffer` and you should be fine.

Comment: Additionally, never cast the return value of `malloc()` in C. It might mask errors.